# Sequence of bijective functions that converge to the identity and compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-topology

Let $\{\psi_{k}\}\in C^{1}(\mathbb{\mathbb{R}}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n})$ by a family of bijective functions such that:
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\|\psi_{k}-x\|_{1,\infty}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\|\psi_{k}^{-1}-x\|_{1,\infty}=0$$

Where $\|f\|_{1,\infty}=\sup\|f\|_{2} + \sup\|\nabla f\|_{2}$. (the family converge to the identity function uniformly)

Given $\Omega$ open and bounded, I want to prove that for every compact set $K\subset\Omega$ there is a $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K \subset \psi_n(\Omega)=\Omega_{n}$, for all $n>n_{0}$.

I have several attempts but nothing good so far. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is $\|f\|_{1,\infty}$ in comparison to $\|f\|_{\infty}$?

Comment: my bad this an error I meant $\|f\|_\infty$

Comment: The triangle inequality is not true for set distance.

Comment: Hint: $d(K,\psi_n(K))\lt \epsilon$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: You'r right about the triangle inequality. :(

Comment: Should I use Hausdorff distance? Or can be done with hint ? I just don't see how that it is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\psi_n$ is a bijection so if $K$ is not a subset of $\psi_n(\Omega)$ then there must exists a $y_n\in\Omega^c$ such that $\psi_n(y_n)\in K$.

Let $\epsilon=\min\{\|k-y\|:k\in K,  y\in\Omega^C\}$ this is well defined as $K$ is compact, $\Omega^c$ is closed, and they are disjoint.

Uniform convergence tells us that there exists a $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ and $x$ we have $\|\psi_n(x)-x\|<\epsilon$. This means that $\psi_n(y)$ cannot be in $K$ for all $y\in\Omega^c$. Hence, $\psi_n(\Omega^C)\subset K^c$ and $K\subset \psi(\Omega)$.